# Present perfect or simple past.. have fallen in love or fell in love

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, past-simple, past-participles

I'm learning present perfect and simple past in English and I have a question, is it correct to say "My parents have fallen in love and have gotten married" or "they fell in love and got married"?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meanings are different.

"My parents have fallen in love and (have) got married" means it has happened *recently*. So you were born before they fell in love and got married. It is possible :-)

You probably need the simple past. "My parents fell in love and got married." This simply means it happened.

Only a newborn baby can say, "I have been born!" Mostly we say, "I was born (in 1970)", "I was born in Scotland" etc.

[Btw, in British English we very rarely use the word *gotten*.]

Comment: Thank you so much! <3